# Can't use argument of js function on JSON

Tags: javascript, arguments

I have an object like this:

```
const myObj = [
{
 "name": "harry",
 "id_1": "j-347",
 "id_2": "j-303"
}, 
{
 "name": "liouk",
 "id_1": "k-398",
 "id_2": "k-945"
}
]
```

If I want to access hary's id_1 (or id_2) I have to type

```
myObj[0].id_1 (or id_2)
```

I have this function:

```
function getId(counter, id) {
 console.log(counter);
 console.log(id)
 console.log(myObj[counter].id;
}
```

but when I call getId(0, "id_1") I get:

```
0
id_1
undefined
```

In addition, if I delete the line "console.log(id)" from the function, my code editor tells me that 'id' is declared but its value is never read, despite the fact that I use it on the last line of the function. 
It seems like the argument "id_1" not be recognized after the . (console.log(myObj[counter]**.**id;)
What do I do wrong?

Comment: u need `myObj[counter][id]`  bcause `.id` looks for property with name id

Answer (score 0):

the function you have written needs a little tweak, as **id** property doesnt exist inside the array u have provided instead u are passing it as string, and it to be placed inside square bracket

```
function getId(counter, id) {
  console.log(counter);
  console.log(id)
  console.log(myObj[counter][id]);
}
```